# Stop MediaScanner scanning of certain directory

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to notify MediaScanner service on Android platform not to scan certain directories? I have application that encrypts images on SD card and after I do that MediaScanner goes wild in LogCat (writing out "not JPEG" exception... and there are time I have over 1000 pics in directory).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a file named `.nomedia` (note the leading dot) in the directory. The file can be 0 bytes in length -- it just has to be there with that name.

Comment: @CommonsWare I put .nomedia fine in my folder containing image but still my images appears in android gallery can you tell me, whats wrong i am doing ?